# Split a string in python

Tags: python, string

```
          a="aaaa#b:c:"
          >>> for i in a.split(":"):
          ...   print i
          ...   if ("#" in i):   //i=aaaa#b
          ...     print only b
```

In the if loop if i=aaaa#b how to get the value after the hash.should we use rsplit to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a="aaaa#b:c:"
>>> a.split(":",2)[0].split("#")[-1]
'b'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following can replace your `if` statement.

```
for i in a.split(':'):
    print i.partition('#')[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "aaaa#b:c:"
print(a.split(":")[0].split("#")[1])
```

Comment: This assumes that `i` contains a '#'. `split('#',1)` and checking the length of the result would be safer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest from: [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

> str.rsplit([sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done, the
>   rightmost ones. If sep is not specified or None, any whitespace string
>   is a separator. Except for splitting from the right, rsplit() behaves
>   like split() which is described in detail below.

so to answer your question yes.

EDIT:

It depends on how you wish to index your strings too, it looks like Rstring does it from the right, so if your data is always "rightmost" you could index by 0 (or 1, not sure how python indexes), every time, rather then having to do a size check of the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

do you really need to use split? split create a list, so isn't so efficient...

what about something like this:

```
>>> a = "aaaa#b:c:"
>>> a[a.find('#') + 1]
'b'
```

or if you need particular occurence, use regex instead...

Answer (score -1):

`split` would do the job nicely. Use `rsplit` only if you need to split from the last '#'.

```
a="aaaa#b:c:"
>>> for i in a.split(":"):
...   print i
...   b = i.split('#',1)
...   if len(b)==2:
...     print b[1]
```